# Redraw Mandelbrot in Bokeh?

Tags: python, charts, mandelbrot, bokeh

I am learning to use Bokeh for an interactive plotting tool. The issue I have is similar to the case in a Mandelbrot chart, when zooming into it, the new area is redraw. This requires BokehJS to send the new X and Y ranges back the Bokeh backend to regenerate the data and send it back to BokehJS to redraw. How can this be done in Bokeh?

Comment: I too would like to know how to force Bokeh to redraw. Did you find an answer?

Comment: I'm also dealing with the similar problem. I can't make and image redraw with source.trigger('change') after changing the image data inside a CustomJS callback function. It works in an ipython notebook using push_notebook() from bokeh.io. But I want to make it work in a static document.

Answer (score 2):

I am the project lead for Bokeh, but I am actually going to recommend that for this you turn to [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/) which is built on top of Bokeh. To do this in pure Bokeh is a bit low level and tedious, because Bokeh does not expose a single unified range update, only low level individual range start/end updates. Using Bokeh directly would require alot of code to throttle and coalesce events to avoid lots of unnecessary re-computation. Holoviews, being at a higher level, has already done all this. Then even have an [interactive Mandlebrot example](http://holoviews.org/gallery/apps/bokeh/mandelbrot.html) ready to run (like any standard Bokeh app). The code (minus the fractal compute parts) looks like this:

```
def get_fractal(x_range, y_range):
    (x0, x1), (y0, y1) = x_range, y_range
    image = np.zeros((600, 600), dtype=np.uint8)
    return hv.Image(create_fractal(x0, x1, -y1, -y0, image, 200),
                    bounds=(x0, y0, x1, y1))

# Define stream linked to axis XY-range
range_stream = RangeXY(x_range=(-1., 1.), y_range=(-1., 1.))

# Create DynamicMap to compute fractal per zoom range and
# adjoin a logarithmic histogram
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(get_fractal, label='Manderbrot Explorer',
                     streams=[range_stream]).hist(log=True)

# Define styling options
options = hv.Store.options('bokeh')
options.Image = {
    'style': Options(cmap='fire'),
    'plot' : Options(logz=True, height=600, width=600,
                     xaxis=None, yaxis=None)
}
options.Histogram = {
    'norm': Options(framewise=True),
    'plot': Options(logy=True, width=200)
}

doc = BokehRenderer.server_doc(dmap)
doc.title = 'Mandelbrot Explorer'
```

[image]